# Android how my old application get know there is an update version for it, now available in play store

Tags: android

I have application that is installed in Android device. later on  I update the apk and provide the new version for it in play store. my question how my application get know, new version for it now available in play store and update it.

Comment: Google Play itself will handle this and notify the user that your application has an update. There is no way that an already installed app can check if there's an update since you haven't implemented such functionality.

Comment: is notify means notification in notification bar or we simply check the same in play store/My Apps

Comment: That depends on the update you're publishing. If it doesn't require any new permissions the update will be automatic in the background otherwise he will get a notification in the notification bar

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, Google Play will handle the updating.  But that doesn't mean you can't put a check into your app that checks to see if a new version is released (by either parsing Google Play data or making a call to your website to get the latest version #) and alerting the user that there's an update available.

But, the user could ignore the update and could have auto-update disabled, and the old app will continue to run just fine.