# update the lauched application in google playstore

Tags: android

I already visited the following questions and searched aroud 4 hours, but no solution sofar

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044193/android-how-my-old-application-get-know-there-is-an-update-version-for-it-now-a

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870626/updating-an-application-in-playstore
```

I have developed an App and has uploaded the same in PlayStore, Now i have some update in my app. I just 'unpublished' my app and trying to upload new apk. But it is giving me error. package name already exist. How can i avoid this and can i directly update my old app

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just 'unpublished' my app

You do not have to unpublished app. Just go to your application and click "apk" from left menu. Upload new apk file there, and move it to production.

> But it is giving me error. package name already exist.

If you will follow above steps, you will not encounter this message.

Note: your new apk's package name must match previous apk's package name. And also you have to sign apk before publishing. I am assume you know all necessary steps.

See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFWxSJLiMbg) for help

Comment: yes, Name is same and i have used the the same signature and have updated the version and code manifest.xml as   android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.1">, but same problem

Comment: you don't have to unpublished app. If you ave done that, republish your app and then just go to apk screen and upload new file

Comment: Hey Penguin, Thanks, Video helped me - I was uploading in "New apk" instead of a"apk to production".. Thanks